# How to post object and List using postman

Tags: json, postman

I am using [postman packaged app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) to send a post request.

I want to request the following controller.

How to send a post requestbody using postman object(with values) and a list using the raw format?

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseMessage save(@RequestBody Freelancer freelancer, @RequestBody List<Integer> skills) {
```

I have tried like this :

```
{
  "address": "colombo",
  "username": "hesh",
  "password": "123",
  "registetedDate": "2015-4-3",
  "firstname": "hesh",
  "contactNo": "07762",
  "accountNo": "16161",
  "lastName": "jay"
}
{
    "array[0]" :1436517454492,
    "array[1]" :1436517476993
}
```

Answer (score 50):

Make sure that you have made the `content-type` as `application/json` in header request and Post from body under the raw tab.

```
{
  "address": "colombo",
  "username": "hesh",
  "password": "123",
  "registetedDate": "2015-4-3",
  "firstname": "hesh",
  "contactNo": "07762",
  "accountNo": "16161",
  "lastName": "jay",
  "arrayObjectName" : [{
    "Id" : 1,
    "Name": "ABC" },
    {
    "Id" : 2,
    "Name" : "XYZ"
  }],
  "intArrayName" : [111,222,333],
  "stringArrayName" : ["a","b","c"]


}
```

Answer (score 16):

I also had a similar question, sharing the below example if it helps.

My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/batchDeleteIndex"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public BaseResponse batchDeleteIndex(@RequestBody List<String> datasetQnames)
```

Postman:
Set the Body type to raw and add header Content-Type: application/json

```
["aaa","bbb","ccc"]
```

Answer (score 14):

**Use this Format as per your requirements:**

```
{
    "address": "colombo",
    "username": "hesh",
    "password": "123",
    "registetedDate": "2015-4-3",
    "firstname": "hesh",
    "contactNo": "07762",
    "accountNo": "16161",
    "lastName": "jay"
    "arrayOneName" : [
        {
            "Id" : 1,
            "Employee" : "EmpOne", 
            "Deptartment" : "HR"
        },
        {
            "Id" : 2,
            "Employee" : "EmpTwo",
            "Deptartment" : "IT"
        },
        {
            "Id" : 3,
            "Employee" : "EmpThree",
            "Deptartment" : "Sales"
        }
    ],
    "arrayTwoName": [
        {
            "Product": "3",
            "Price": "6790"
        }
    ],
    "arrayThreeName" : [
        "name1", "name2", "name3", "name4" // For Strings
    ],
    "arrayFourName" : [
        1, 2, 3, 4 // For Numbers
    ]

}
```

**Remember to use this in POST with proper endpoint. Also, RAW selected and JSON(application/json) in Body Tab.**

***Like THIS:***

[image]

**Update 1:**

I don't think multiple @RequestBody is allowed or possible.

**@RequestBody parameter must have the entire body of the request and bind that to  only one object.**

**You have to use something like Wrapper Object for this to work.**

Answer (score 6):

In case of simple example if your api is below

```
@POST
    @Path("update_accounts")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @PermissionRequired(Permissions.UPDATE_ACCOUNTS)
    void createLimit(List<AccountUpdateRequest> requestList) throws RuntimeException;
```

where AccountUpdateRequest :

```
public class AccountUpdateRequest {
    private Long accountId;
    private AccountType accountType;
    private BigDecimal amount;
...
}
```

then your postman request would be:
http://localhost:port/update_accounts

```
[
         {
            "accountType": "LEDGER",
            "accountId": 11111,
            "amount": 100
         },
         {
            "accountType": "LEDGER",
            "accountId": 2222,
            "amount": 300
          },
         {
            "accountType": "LEDGER",
            "accountId": 3333,
            "amount": 1000
          }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what server side technology you are using but try using a json array.  A couple of options for you to try:

```
{
  "address": "colombo",
  "username": "hesh",
  "password": "123",
  "registetedDate": "2015-4-3",
  "firstname": "hesh",
  "contactNo": "07762",
  "accountNo": "16161",
  "lastName": "jay"
 },
[
   1436517454492,
   1436517476993
]
```

If that doesn't work you may also try:

```
{
  freelancer: {
  "address": "colombo",
  "username": "hesh",
  "password": "123",
  "registetedDate": "2015-4-3",
  "firstname": "hesh",
  "contactNo": "07762",
  "accountNo": "16161",
  "lastName": "jay"
 },
 skills : [
       1436517454492,
       1436517476993
    ]
}
```

Comment: ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved for both

Comment: This sounds like it is an issue on the server.  Please ensure the services is up and running.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    "preOrderData" : [
        {
            "pname": "xyz",
            "quantity": "1",
            "unit": "Peice",
            "description": "xyz 100 gram",
            "preferred_brand": "xyz",
            "entry_date": "2020-10-05 11:11:27",
            "creation_date": "2020-10-05 11:11:27",
            "updated_date": "2020-10-05 11:11:27",
            "user": "ABC@gmail.com",
            "user_type": "individual"
        },
        {
            "productname": "abc cream",
            "quantity": "1",
            "unit": "Peice",
            "description": "abc 100 gram",
            "preferred_brand": "abccream",
            "entry_date": "2020-10-05 11:11:27",
            "creation_date": "2020-10-05 11:11:27",
            "updated_date": "2020-10-05 11:11:27",
            "user": "xyz@gmail.com",
            "user_type": "individual"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: get the data through req.body.preOrderData

Answer (score 0):

//backend.

```
@PostMapping("/")
public List<A> addList(@RequestBody A aObject){
//......ur code
}

class A{
int num;
String name;
List<B> bList;
//getters and setters and default constructor
}
class B{
int d;
//defalut Constructor & gettes&setters
}
```

// postman

```
{
"num":value,
"name":value,
"bList":[{
"key":"value",
"key":"value",.....
}]
}
```

1. the error is for list there is no default constructor .so we can keep our list of object as a property of another class and pass the list of objects through the postman as the parameter of the another class.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following format in your request section while making sure the request url is of http://localhost:XXXX/OperationName/V#.

```
      {
      "address": "colombo",
      "username": "hesh",
      "password": "123",
      "registetedDate": "2015-4-3",
      "firstname": "hesh",
      "contactNo": "07762",
      "accountNo": "16161",
      "lastName": "jay",         
      "listName":[
       {
        "elementOne":"valueOne"
       },
       {
        "elementTwo":"valueTwo"
       },
       ...]
     }
```

Comment: Hi! This answer came up in review as low quality because of its length and content. This happens because code only answers are generally discouraged on SO and should be accompanied by some text explanation of how the code is a solution to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Updated accordingly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
{
  "address": "colombo",
  "username": "hesh",
  "password": "123",
  "registetedDate": "2015-4-3",
  "firstname": "hesh",
  "contactNo": "07762",
  "accountNo": "16161",
  "lastName": "jay",
  "skill":[1436517454492,1436517476993]
}
```