# how to send a list of id's in postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, postman

I have a spring boot project where I need to expose a few APIs.
I have 2 entities and what I would like to do is to be able to send list of id's of one of the entities in postman.
Any idea how can I do it?
this is how my json looks as of now: `"productIds": [{ "productId":1 }, {"productId":2 }, { "productId":3 }]` 
basically Product is an entity and I don't want to send in the request the entire object, only it's id

Comment: The JSON in your question is valid and could be parsed in your backend. So what's the question?

Comment: [Check this post if it helps to you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31337914/how-to-post-object-and-list-using-postman#:~:text=Postman%3A%20Set%20the%20Body%20type%20to%20raw%20and%20add%20header%20Content%2DType%3A%20application/json)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a POJO mapping class

```
class Pojo {
 private List<AnotherPojo> productIds;
}

class AnotherPojo {
 private long productId;
} 

and add in controller as below

@GetMapping("uri")
public Object get(@RequestBody Pojo pojo){
   // log pojo
}

 { "productIds": [{ "productId":1 }, {"productId":2 }, { "productId":3 }] }
```

When calling from post man, add header Content-type: application-json

Comment: what if I have other properties in the Pojo class? would I still be able to use only the id's?

Comment: Yes u can use @JsonIgnore to ignore other properties, all other properties in pogo will be null